# differential systems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-topology

all the answers for the equation $$\ddot{y}=ye^{t+\dot{y}}$$ can be reached from solving the threee dimension system of $$\dot{X}=F(X)$$ with considering $$y(t)=x_2(t)$$ and $$F\begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\\x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1\\x_1\\x_2e^{x_1+x_3}\end{bmatrix}$$ is this statement true ?

Comment: This question is missing the question. What exactly is unclear about that task? Do you understand the idea of an equivalent first order system? // Note also the variant of this task in https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3740133/115115. Do you see the difference?

Answer (score 1):

No. You have variables $(t,y(t),\dot y(t))$, so the second component of the vector field $F$ should be $x_3$.